# which sql statement should be correct?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sql question.

web_requests: date, user_id, browser [chrome, firefox, ie], request_count

api_reques‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‌‍‌‌‌‌‌‍‌‌ts: date, user_id, devide_type [iphone, ipad, android-phone], request_count

Goal: get the per-day count since the beginning of the year of users ‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‌‍‌‌‌‌‌‍‌‌ who visited at least one page on an iphone and the web on the same day

I've tried two different sql here, I want to know which one should be better?

1.

```
select w.date, sum(w.user_id) + count(a.user_id) as per-day-count
from 
(select * from web_requests where date >= '2017-01-01') as w

inner join

(select * from api_requets where device_type = 'iphone' and date >= '2017-01-01') as a
on w.date = a.date and w.user_id = a.user_id
```

2.

```
select date, count(distinct use‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‌‍‌‌‌‌‌‍‌‌r_id) as users
    from
    (
            select date, user_id
            from api_request
            where device_type = 'iphone' and date >= '2017-01-01' and request_count > 0
            UNION
            select date, user_id
            from web_request
            where date >= '2017-01-01' and request_count > 0
    ) a
    group by date
```

Comment: Which one gives you the results you expect/want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build this query something like this. First is to get the `count()` within `union` and get the `sum` of the resulting table.

```
select date, sum(ct) from (
    select count(1) as ct, user_id, date, 'web' as src from web_requests 
        where date >= '2017-01-01'
        group by date, user_id
    union
    select count(1) as ct, user_id, date, 'api' as src from api_requets 
        where device_type = 'iphone' and date >= '2017-01-01'
        group by date, user_id
) t1
group by t1.date
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefer inner join queries over others solutions. It would perform better.